# how to create linked server with remote access database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I want to create linked server object of Access file with SQL server 2008. the Access file is located on different server other than SQL server 2008.

I am able to create the linked server object if the file is located on same server.

please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OPENDATASOURCE` or `OPENROWSET` to access the Access DB. and you have to share the file on network

you can get more information from [here](http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2009/03/02/read-xls-or-mdb-file-with-opendatasource-sql-server-2005/)